# Changing data in Matlab to correlate to sampling frequency

Tags: matlab

Good day,
I have a document of data measured during experiments. The first columns of the document is time thereafter torque and displacement readings. 
My measuring equipment were supposed to sample at 200Hz, however during the experiment as the measured data increased the computer slowed down resulting in sampling rates lower than 200Hz. 
I however require readings at an exact sampling frequency (anything between 0 and 200Hz is acceptable), how can I modify/interpolate my data to correlate to the desired frequency?

Comment: You need to include some sample data to make this question answerable. Show a sample of what you have, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: If you sampled at less than 200Hz, how can you hope to recover high frequency data? Do you have valid strong smoothness assumptions on your data?

Answer (score 0):

For general resampling, use the `resample` function (see its [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/signal/ref/resample.html) for examples of use). It lets you specify the resampling factor as a rational number, with the limitation that the numerator and denominator can't be too large. That imposes restrictions when the resampling factor is very close to 1; other than that it is the way to go.

If you need to be very fine with your resampling factor (por example, correcting sampling frequency by amounts of the order of 1 part per million, which requires a resampling factor very close to 1), I suggest you use linear interpolation with the function `interp1` (see its [doc](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)). This interpolation method is not as good as that of resample, but the error is negligible for resampling factors close to 1, and it lets you very fine control of the resampling factor.